# JPA CriteriaBuilder substring with Expression

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a CriteriaBuilder where I am trying to get characters starting from 1 to (LengthOfString - 5). However I am not able to get the desired output. Below is my desired output.

```
select
            *
        from tbl_job job1_     

        inner join
            tbl_customer customer2_ 
                on job1_.customer_id=customer2_.id 
        where
            job1_.customer_id=customer2_.id 
                    and //

        group by SUBSTRING(job1_.code,1,(LENGTH(job1_.code)-5))
```

And I have tried this way, but my IDE depict the error under the **(cb.length(root.get("code"))-5)** "The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) Expression, int".

```
final Specification<Job> specification = (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("code"))); 
            query.groupBy(cb.substring(root.get("code"), 1 , (cb.length(root.get("code"))-5) ));
            return cb.and(
                    //...
        };
```

hat could be the reason for this?
Thanks for any help advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `Expression<Integer>` holding the result of the subtraction and use it in the `substring` method:

```
Expression<Integer> lengthMinus5 = cb.sum(cb.length(root.get("code")), -5);
Expression<Integer> one = cb.literal(1);
query.groupBy(cb.substring(root.get("code"), one , lengthMinus5 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect the types of the operands of `cb.length(root.get("code"))-5`.
Left side is `Expression`, right side is `int`. There is no operator `-` handling that.

You have to include the calculation `-5` in your expression.